# how to explain the output of this C program?

Tags: c

```
main() {
  printf("AAA"+2);
  printf ("%c","A"+printf(" B")+printf ("C "));
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what will be the output and how its coming?

Comment: don't you have a compiler on your machine?

Comment: Why write such incomprehensible code?

Comment: yes i do, but i can't understand how the output is coming. i don't need the output,as i can get it by running the code, i want to know the logic behind it.

Comment: `man printf` (or google..)?

Comment: it was a question of GATE(test to get into the premier engineering institutes of india for M.Tech).

Comment: So you want us to answer a question for you to get into an institution?

Comment: second sentence is UB.

Comment: i am preparing for the entrance, and i am not able to get the logic behind it. asking help from the experts, if you can't do it on your own is a sin or what?

Comment: @user3773893 - Why not accept the answer

Answer (score 6):

Line 1

```
 printf("AAA"+2);
```

"AAA" is an array of four characters (3 A and the null). So will print the array from index 2 onwards. i.e. "A"

Line 2:

```
 printf ("%c","A"+printf(" B")+printf ("C "));
```

Divide this up

```
 printf(" B")
```

Will print " B" and returns 2 (as per the manual page)

The

```
 printf("C ")
```

Will print "C " and return 2

So the string "A" is an an array of 2 characters (A and null).

But got ("A" + 2)  + 2) and the 2 is out of the range of the string.

So this bit is undefined

Comment: Is the `+` right associative?

Comment: @thebjorn - You are correct and I was in the process of correcting myself.